# Can I schedule Docker to run on specific time on Amazon ECS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, amazon-ecs

I want to schedule my docker image to run on a specific time on every day or if the size of a particular folder in my Amazon S3 reached a threshold size? Is it possible? (Any of these case)

Answer (score 1):

There's no build in scheduler from AWS to do this.

Anyway,

you can either run a cronjob on a different machine and use the API to start a task on ECS (http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/APIReference/API_RunTask.html)

or

you can create a Lambda function that runs your task (http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-scheduled-events.html)